# awk to print line greater than zero in column 1

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to print the name of directories whose free space is greater than zero.

```
  #Listed all the directory and their consumed space.
    du -sm storage*
    365     storage1
    670     storage2
    1426    storage3
```

I have threshold value of 1000M , so I am trying to print free space in these directories relative to threshold value provided.

```
du -sm storage* | awk -v threshold="1000" '$1>0{print $1=threshold-$1,$2}'
635 storage1
330 storage2
-426 storage3
```

So , I want to print those directories whose free size is positive integer. Something like :

```
635 storage1
330 storage2
```

Any correction ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you use threshold for

Comment: I want to set restriction on each directory size. NO directory should grow bigger then 1000M.

Comment: So `0 < size < threshold`, ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this got overly complicated. If you just want to check that the size is positive and lower than a given threshold, say so:

```
awk -v threshold=1000 '0 < $1 && $1 < threshold'
```

#### Test

```
$ cat file
635 storage1
330 storage2
-426 storage3

$ awk -v thr=1000 '0 < $1 && $1 < thr' file
635 storage1
330 storage2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write it like this,

```
awk -v threshold="1000" '{$1=threshold-$1} $1 > 0'
```

**Example**

```
awk -v threshold="1000" '{$1=threshold-$1} $1 > 0' input
635 storage1
330 storage2
```

**What it does?**

- `$1=threshold-$1` Sets the first column relative to the threshold.
- `$1 > 0` Checks if the derived first column is greater than zero. If this expression evaluates true, it prints the entire input line.

Comment: Nice. Since this in idiomatic way of doing awk stuff, It is good for the op to read the [\[ awk info \]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) too.

Answer (score 2):

Just check `$1 > 0` in `awk`

```
du -sm storage*|awk '{if ( $1 > 0 ) print }'
```

or

```
du -sm storage*|awk  '$1>0'
```

Comment: Idiomatically: `awk '$1>0'`

Comment: Thanks @ fedorqui . added this syntax too.

Comment: well, some like doing things the hard way ;)